# Prove that a maximal ideal is radical.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $m$ be a maximal ideal of commutative ring $R$. Prove that $m$ is radical.

I understand that $m$ is maximal if it is proper and there are no other ideals (except $R$) that properly contain it. In other words, $m$ is the "highest" ideal, as in if we have an ideal $n$ and $m \subseteq n$ then $m = n$ or $n = R$. I also understand that an ideal, $m$, is radical if $m = \sqrt m $ where $\sqrt m = \{ f \in k[x_1,x_2,...x_m] | f^m \in m\}$.

What do I have to do to show that the if $m$ is maximal then it is also radical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt{\mathscr{m}} = \{ r \in R | r^n \in \mathscr{m} \, \text{for some integer} \, n\}$.

To show that $\mathscr{m} = \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$, we simply show that $\sqrt{\mathscr{m}} \subseteq \mathscr{m}$ because we already have that $\mathscr{m} \subseteq \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$ since we can take $n=1$ for every $x \in \mathscr{m}$.

Take any $x \in \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$. This implies $x^n \in \mathscr{m}$ for some $n$. Thus $x \in \mathscr{m}$ because $\mathscr{m}$ is also a prime ideal.

Comment: Can you please expand on how we know that $m \subseteq \sqrt m$?

Comment: @Masha For $x \in \mathscr{m}$, we have $x^1 \in \mathscr{m}$ which implies $x \in \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$.

Comment: Do we know that it is $x^1$ because it is the maximal ideal, so therefore it cannot have any higher power?

Comment: @Masha Sorry I'm not quite sure what you're asking in your comment so the following may not be an answer to that but you don't have to worry about weather  $x^1$ belongs to $\mathscr{m}$ because $x^1 = x$. This does not involve taking any higher powers of $\mathscr{m}$ or anything else as such.

Comment: Sorry, my question is we know that $x^1 \in m$ but why does this show that therefore $m \subset sqrt(m)$ ?

Comment: @Masha Ah, so you just have to look at the definition of $\sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$ given in my answer (where I should say that I've missed the word 'positive' integer). An element of the ring $R$ is in $\sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$ if any positive power of it is in $\mathscr{m}$. We picked an arbitrary element $x \in \mathscr{m} \subsetneq R$ and noted that because $(x =) x^1 \in \mathscr{m}$, by defintion we then have that $ x\in \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$, given us the required set inclusion. I hope this makes it clear for you.

Comment: I came up with a slightly different proof to show that $\sqrt(m) \subset m$. Can you please let me know if this makes sense, based off of what you said? If we assume by contradiction that $\sqrt(m) \not \subset m$ then $\sqrt(m)$ is in between $m$ and the entire ring $R$. So if $\sqrt(m) = R$ then by the definition of a radical, $1 \in \sqrt(m)$ and then $1^n \in m$. But if $1 \in m$ then $m = R$. This is a contradiction because we know that $m$ is maximal and then therefore cannot equal $R$. Hence $\sqrt(m) \neq R$ and so $\sqrt(m) \subset m$

Comment: @Masha, In the end I would write and so $\mathscr{m} = \sqrt{\mathscr{m}}$, but your proof is correct.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have to show the following, for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$:

1. $\sqrt{\mathfrak m}\supseteq\mathfrak m$
2. $\sqrt{\mathfrak m} \ne R$.

To show, e.g., assertion 2, it suffices to prove $1_R\not\in\sqrt{\mathfrak m}$. What would happen if $1_R\in\sqrt{\mathfrak m}$?

Comment: Would this be correct? If we take $m$ and raise it to some power $h$ then we have $m^h$. But, we know that $m$ is maximal, so there can be no ideal, $J$, where $m \subset J$. Therefore, $m^h = m$. If $m^h=m$ then we know that $m$ is radical and therefore $m$ is both maximal and radical. For the second part, if $1_R \in m$ then $m$ would not be maximal. So, $1_R$ cannot be in the radical.

Comment: @Masha Oddly enough, a power of an ideal $I$ is contained in $I$. Think of the ring $\Bbb Z$, in which $\langle 4\rangle=(\langle 2\rangle)^2$ is properly contained in $\langle 2\rangle$. What if you instead try to prove (1) directly: what do you have to show to prove a set is contained in another? For (2), that was a typo - suppose $1_R\in\sqrt{\mathfrak m}$ and see what happens.

Comment: Would I have to show that everything in the set of maximal ideals is also in the set of radicals? I'm still a little confused as to how to go about that proof